# Laravel Sessions: on page reload (refresh) display the other group of images

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I want to create a simple app that displays a group of images (banners), and when a page is reloaded - it should display the other group of images.

Each image has a property called `order` which is an integer.
For example, when you open the home page for the first time, three images with `order` values in **[1, 3, 5]** should be displayed. After the page reload, then the images with `order` values in **[2, 4, 6]** should be displayed. And if you re-open the page again - then the images with `order` values in **[1, 3, 5]** should be displayed again. And so on...

So, basically, images with `order` values in **[1, 3, 5]** and **[2, 4, 6]** should toggle on every page reload.

In my controller I've tried the following:

```
public function index() {

    if (!\Session::has('top_order')) {
        $top_banners = TopBanner::where('position', 'top')
            ->whereIn('order', [1, 3, 5])
            ->orderBy('order')
            ->get();
        \Session::put('top_order', [2, 4, 6]);
    } else {
        $next_orders = \Session::get('top_order');

        $top_banners = TopBanner::where('position', 'top')
            ->whereIn('order', $next_orders)
            ->orderBy('order')
            ->get();

        if ($next_orders[0] == 1) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($next_orders); $i++) {
                $next_orders[$i]++;
            }
        } else {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($next_orders); $i++) {
                $next_orders[$i]--;
            }
        }

        \Session::put('top_order', $next_orders);
    }

    return view('welcome')->with('top_banners', $top_banners);   
}
```

But for some reason, the images are not toggled. As you can see in the else block, when a page is reloaded (when an HTTP request is sent and the `index` method in the controller is executed) - first I get from the `'top_order'` session the next group of images that should be displayed:

```
$next_orders = \Session::get('top_order');
```

... and then I want to update the `'top_order'` session - I want to set its value to the other order group. So, if the current value of the `'top_order'` session is  **[1, 3, 5]** - then update it to **[2, 4, 6]**:

```
        if ($next_orders[0] == 1) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($next_orders); $i++) {
                $next_orders[$i]++;
            }
        }
```

... and if the current value of the `'top_order'` session is  **[2, 4, 6]** - then update it to **[1, 3, 5]**:

```
        else {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($next_orders); $i++) {
                $next_orders[$i]--;
            }
        }
```

Finally, save:

```
\Session::put('top_order', $next_orders);
```

But it doesn't work and I can't see what am I doing wrong. 
Once the `'top_order'` session is set to **[2, 4, 6]** - it stay there, only that group of images will be displayed no matter how many times I refresh the page.

Comment: you can clean up your code alot

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index() {
$first_order = [1,3,5];
$second_order = [2,4,6];
if (!\Session::has('top_order')) {
    \Session::put('top_order', $first_order);
} else {
    \Session::put('top_order', (\Session::get('top_order') == $first_order) : $second_order ? $first_order));
}
    $top_banners = TopBanner::where('position', 'top')
        ->whereIn('order', \Session::get('top_order'))
        ->orderBy('order')
        ->get();

    return view('welcome')->with('top_banners', $top_banners);   
}
```

Try this code. If it doesn't work I would suggest replacing the session with cookies.

Comment: The `put` method requires two arguments: *session key* and *session value* (`put('key', 'value')`) https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session. So your **else** block will not work because  you have `\Session::put('top_order') = ( ... `.

Comment: sorry I was in a hurry when i answered. I edited it now this should work.